# Not able to show custom message after click custom submit action button

Tags: sitecore-forms

I want to show custom message after click the custom submit action button, In this form, how we can assign the message and show above button. could you please provide the solution of this scenario.

[image]

example:

sample code:

```
public class CustomSubmitAction : SubmitActionBase<string>
    {
        private FormSubmitContext _formSubmitContext;
        public CustomSubmitAction(ISubmitActionData submitActionData) : base(submitActionData)
        {
        }    
        protected override bool Execute(string data, FormSubmitContext formSubmitContext)
        {

        try
        {
            this._formSubmitContext = formSubmitContext;
            var nameFieldValue = GetValue(this._formSubmitContext.Fields.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name.Equals("txtName")));
            var emailFieldValue = GetValue(this._formSubmitContext.Fields.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name.Equals("txtMail")));

            using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
            {
                //email functinality
                //smtp.Send(mail);  scenario1 -->if email send successfully, i have to show custom message like "Message is send successfully"
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error($" mail failed ", e, this);
            formSubmitContext.Abort(); //scenario-2-- >if email failed, i have to show custom message like "Message is not send successfully"
        }
        return false;
    }
    protected override bool TryParse(string value, out string target)
    {
        target = string.Empty;
        return true;
    }
    private static string GetValue(object field)
    {
        return field?.GetType().GetProperty("Value")?.GetValue(field, null)?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would say you will need a custom submit action and possibly a custom field for the success message. Sitecore provide doco explaining how to build both. Can you show us your code and describe the specific error you encountered?

Comment: above mentioned the sample code.